# SQL sum with subquery

Tags: sql, sum

I use SQL Server 2014 express.

When I execute query :

```
select (select MAX(czasy)  from (values (czas),(czas_trw)) as all_val(czasy)) as czas1 
from projekty_etapy2 pe2 where pe2.id_projektu=34
```

everything working ok

But when I want sum all values from this query by runing

```
 select sum (czas1) FROM (

select (select MAX(czasy)  from (values (czas),(czas_trw)) as all_val(czasy)) as czas1 
from projekty_etapy2 pe2 where pe2.id_projektu=34)
```

I receive error about wrong syntax ')' near id_projektu=34 -why ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an allias.

```
SELECT SUM(czas1) 
FROM 
(     
    SELECT 
    (
        SELECT MAX(czasy)  
        FROM 
        (
            VALUES (czas),(czas_trw)
        ) AS all_val(czasy)
    ) AS czas1 
    FROM projekty_etapy2 pe2 
    WHERE pe2.id_projektu=34
) AS T;
```